# Create custom dynamic link on form that directs to another page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am attempting to create a list of items and when the user clicks on the link, it passes the tank serial number to the next form.

Here is what I have so far but how do I make it linkable and pass a tank serial to the next page:

My TankList in my controller:

```
    public ActionResult TankList()
    {

      var tanklist = new List<string>();
      tanklist.Add("1234566777");
      tanklist.Add("62523456345");
      tanklist.Add("8924545454");
      tanklist.Add("34556855433");
      tanklist.Add("933456643437");

      ViewBag.TankList = tanklist;

      return View();
    }
```

My TankList.cshtml:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Tanks Serial Numbers";
}
<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>
<h3>@ViewBag.Message</h3>

<p>Please select the tank that you wish to administer:</p>

<div>


  @foreach (var list in ViewBag.Tanklist)
  {
    <a href="/Forms/AsmeBasic/@list">@list</a>
    <br />
  }

</div>
```

I wanted to clarify that the above seems to work, at least it creates the link correctly:

[image]

My AsmeBasic ActionResult in my controller:

```
    public ActionResult AsmeBasic(string tankserial)
    {
      ViewBag.TankSerial = tankserial;

      return View();
}
```

The list is being populated but the serial number is not being passed. I'm getting a null value for tankserial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok you need to add a couple things in your HTML.

```
  @foreach (var list in ViewBag.Tanklist)
  {
    <a href="/Forms/AsmeBasic?tankserial=@list">@list</a>
    <br />
  }
```

You can also use tag helpers to make it easier.

```
  @foreach (var list in ViewBag.Tanklist)
  {

    <a asp-action="AsmeBasic" asp-route-tankserial="@list">@list</a>

    <br />
  }
```

Comment: @ErocM I updated my answer to give you a easier way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have format issue.

You can use `Html.ActionLink` helper method to generate the hyper link which will take care of adding the query string parameter in it's correct format:

```
@foreach (var list in ViewBag.Tanklist)
  {
    @Html.ActionLink(list, // <-- Link text  
             "AsmeBasic", // <-- Action Method Name  
             "Forms", // <-- Controller Name  
             new { tankserial = list }, // <-- Route value  
             null // <-- htmlArguments  
             )
    <br />
  }
```

Comment: I like this method better, seems cleaner. I will give it a try.